# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number Помогите с INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

в общем не могу понять в чем дело, функция работает с другими данными,отключается после добавления данных об access и status:

Вот изначальный код:

```
if ($_POST) {
        $data = $_POST;
        $data['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
        $data['acсess'] = 'user';
        $data['status'] = 'activ';
        print_r($data);
        if (DBselect('*', 'users', 'email', $data['email'],false) or  DBselect('*', 'users', 'tel', $data['tel'],false)) {
            echo 'Не знаю от куда Вы его взяли, но такой клиент уже есть в базе, другой раз повезет';
        }
        else {
            DBinsert('users',$data);
        }
    }
```

Вот сама функция добавления:

```
function DBinsert($_table, array $_data_insert): bool
    {
        global $pdo;
        //$_data
        $_data_key = array_keys($_data_insert); //из массива достает все ключи
        $_data_key_str = implode(',', $_data_key);
        $_data_value_str = ':' . implode(',:', $_data_key);
        $data = $_data_insert;
        //print_r($data);
        //echo "INSERT INTO {$_table} ({$_data_key_str}) VALUES ({$_data_value_str})";
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO {$_table} ({$_data_key_str}) VALUES ({$_data_value_str})");
        //print_r($data);
        if (!$sql) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
        }
        echo "INSERT INTO {$_table} ({$_data_key_str}) VALUES ({$_data_value_str})";
        $sql->execute($data);
        echo 'Запись добавлена, давай следующую =)';
        return true;
    }
```

Обычно при выводе через echo данных понятно в чем проблема (обычно запятая), но тут что то все вроде проверил, или глаз уже замылился или что то делаю не правильно, просвятите плизз.

Вывод print_r ($data):

> Array ( [name] => Гриша [tel] => +8555555555 [region] => Казань
>   [email] => vv@vv.ru [password] => a9d89a1b2e6845b7e2a7d6fc37ce5f11
>   [koment] => ghje\ [partner_id] => 0 [acсess] => user [status] => activ
>   )

Вывод echo `"INSERT INTO {$_table} ({$_data_key_str}) VALUES ({$_data_value_str})"`:

> INSERT INTO users
>   (name,tel,region,email,password,koment,partner_id,acсess,status)
>   VALUES
>   (:name,:tel,:region,:email,:password,:koment,:partner_id,:acсess,:status)

Полное описание ошибки:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   D:\Project\zzz.lk.ru\lk\include\db.php:146 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Project\zzz.lk.ru\lk\include\db.php(146):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   D:\Project\zzz.lk.ru\lk\modul\addclient.php(56): DBinsert('users',
>   Array) #2 D:\Project\zzz.lk.ru\lk\home.php(65):
>   include('D:\Project\zzz....') #3 {main} thrown in
>   D:\Project\zzz.lk.ru\lk\include\db.php on line 146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна из причин такой ошибки - недопустимые символы в имени плейсхолдера. Например русская буква вместо англиийской. Чтобы проверить, надо скопировать имя плейсхолдера и вывести через urlencode:

```
 echo urlencode("acсess status");
```

и сразу будет видно где не латинские буквы.

Но главная проблема этого кода конечно не в банальной опечатке, а в том что он, как это часто бывает с подобными функциями, открыт нараспашку для всех **SQL инъекций**, поскольку напрямую вставляет содержимое РНР переменных в SQL запрос. Что делать категорически не рекомендуется, если только это содержимое не прописано явно в РНР.

Такое стремление "автоматизировать" составление запросов практически всегда приводит к инъекциям. Это тот случай, когда не надо лениться, а надо явно прописать все имена полей, которые доступны для изменения. И проще всего это сделать без всякой функции, а просто написав запрос руками. Это совсем не так трудно, как кажется, осоебно если использовать позиционные плейсхолдеры, а не именованные - с которыми писанины, действительно, получается выше крыши.

Но если так прям совсем невмоготу писать вручную, то хотя бы проверить, что в ключах массива у нас действительно нужные имена полей, а не трехэтажная SQL инъекция:

```
function DBinsert($pdo, $table, array $data, array $allowed)
{
    $keys = array_keys($data);
    if (array_diff($keys, $allowed)) {
        throw new ErrorException('Incorrect field name');
    }
    $keys_str = '`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`';
    $values_str = str_repeat('?,', count($keys) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` ($keys_str) VALUES ($values_str)");
    $sql->execute(array_values($data));
}
```

Соответственно, перед исползованием прописать все имена полей в массив и передать в функцию

```
    $data = $_POST;
    $data['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $data['acсess'] = 'user';
    $data['status'] = 'activ';
    $allowed = ['name', 'password','email', 'access', 'status'];
    DBinsert($pdo, 'users', $data, $allowed);
```

как видно, это совсем нетрудно, но зато можно быть спокойным за безопасность и такой код не стыдно выкладывать на всеобщее обозрение.

Comment: Спасибо, я воспользовался Вашим советом и добавил проверку в функцию добавления, что бы передаваемые ключи сверялись в ключами в массиве. Хотел уточнить (загуглил и не понял), throw new ErrorException - если найдет несоответствие прекратит выполнение кода на странице и выдаст ошибку? Не нужно ли помещать выполнение ИНСЕРТА в if - типа если ключи в массиве соответствуют переданным ключам, то выполни ИНСЕРТ, а если нет то выдай ошибку (просто в вашем коде есть проверка, но код по добавлению не в if? Сорри если мои вопросы глупы =)

Comment: Исключение прерывает выполнение кода, и соответственно в случае ошибки весь код ниже не будет выполнен.

Comment: Извините, еще 2 уточняющих вопроса (если вам не сложно): 01. Можно ли делать такую проверку на стороне подготовки запроса (во втором коде который вы привели в ответе).? 02. Не пойму логику, вот я сверил ключи, но основная опасность в данном случае это добавление пользователя нового например с правами access = > admin,  данная функция этого не позволяет, так как по умолчанию ставит access=> user. Нужно ли делать проверку на недопустимые значения (П.С. эти функции добавить нового пользователя будут доступны только администрации сайта, так как регистрация не публичная).

Comment: 1. Можно, но нежелательно. Функция DBinsert() сейчас универсальная, может использоваться где угодно (как это и задумывалось, я полагаю). А если проверку вынести отдельно, то получится уже какой-то паровоз с прицепом, "вот у нас функция, но сам у по себе её нельзя использовать, вот ещё код". Зачем?  В текущем виде функция занимается только SQL, и делает это хорошо, не пропуская инъекции. Так её и оставить. 2. В данном случае конкретное значение не имеет отношения к SQL, а относится к логике приложения. Поэтому правильно будет делать установку значения там где она сейчас - во втором блоке.

Comment: Но в общем конечно вместо фильтрации можно проискейпить идентификаторы, https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert_helper

Comment: привет, хочу что бы Вы знали... (типа оправдание ваше любимое) - я реально внедрил Ваш код и честно благодарен за него. (могу прислать скриншоты). В общем то все получилось по нубски, я разбирался с гит хабом и случайно залил не в ту сторону с домашнего компа, а как прищел в офис опубликовал вопрос не заметив что код старый. Пофиг там на рейтинг, но вы мне помогли и я реально знаю ценность помощи, хотел что бы Вы знали. Кроме того, не знаю насколько это правильно, но я сделал фукнцию по которой алловед делается автоматически на основании заполненных полей.

Comment: Что значит - на основании заполненных полей? На основании массива $_POST?

Comment: да, есть смещение по этому поводу, конечно вот такую штуку сделал: function greatallowed($_data):array {
    foreach ($_data as $key => $value) {
        $return_data[]=$key;
    }
    return $return_data;
} - есть ощущение что это не правильно, но в некоторых функциях добавления у меня разное количество полей в зависимости от содержания

Comment: Господи, надо же настолько не понимать что ты делаешь. Забудь про фильтрацию, делай искейпинг, как показано по ссылке в первом комменты.

Comment: Господь тут не причем =) вотт, array_diff($_data_key, $_allowed - если я помещю в $_allowed все возможные ключи, которые могут быть в запросе (на основании формы), но в $_data ,буду передавать только заполненные поля - то все равно же будет работать? ОН будет возвращать массив в ключами, и if будет показывать true (не ругайтесь я по сути меньше месяца как программист).

Comment: Если ты в allowed помещаешь ключи на основании формы, то эта проверка теряет ВСЯКИЙ смысл. Забудь вообще про allowed, ты все равно из-за своей лени превращаешь эту проверку в тыкву. Делай искейпинг

Comment: Ты тут давеча вещал про мотивацию. У меня она конечно зашкаливает, когда я пишу функцию в которой примерно 200 улучшений по сравнению с твоим говнокодом, из которых ты в виде одолжения берешь только одно, да и то умудряешься испортить

Comment: Ну ок, кому я что вещал тут вчера про мотивацию невкурсе, но вы меня совершенно не знаете, и не нужно мне ТЫкать, я не малолетка какая то, есть области где по сравнению со мной вы такой же нуб...  да и жизнь не строится вокруг одного кода. Я учусь, как могу учится для себя - я могу прожить и без программирования, изучаю не от нехватки денег.. да сделал, да понял что дейсвительно не привильно, так как не понял изначально как работает array_diff - кроме того тут еще другие проблемы. Не кому не каких одолжений я не делаю, я реально Вам багодарен, но видимо всех сравнивайте с собой и обсераете.

Comment: Вчера получилось не красиво, я сам людей обучаю и понимаю как бесят те кому помогаешь, а они даже не пытаются что то изменить. Поэтому искрине, написал Вам благодарность.... только по этому, мне не чего не нужно от Вас.. можете вообще меня игнорить... не какой благосклонности или рейтинга, или даже хороших мыслей про меня мне от вас не нужно. Но сразу обсерать, так часто пишите про лень, что кажется это у вас такие проблемы, а не у меня.